# Pygame display multiple images randomly

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am working with pygame and I was able to draw multiple lines on a screen. I made with this command:

```
for x in range(60,940,20):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, [x, 0], [x, 500], 1)
```

I now need to draw multiple images on the screen. I was able to draw one image by doing:

```
player_two = pygame.image.load("player_two.png").convert()
player_two.set_colorkey(white)



while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        screen.blit(player_two, [60, 240])

        pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

I need to draw multiple of this object EITHER randomly within a range of [60, 0], [220, 475] #OR within the same range but with set coordinates. BOTH instances I need these images to move #randomly within that range in either x and/or y direction with a distance of the size of the #image (jump).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create multi players

```
import random

multi_players = []
multi_players_pos = []

player = pygame.image.load("player_two.png").convert()
player.set_colorkey(white)

#create 10 players 0...9
for i in range(10):
    multi_players.append(player)
    pos = [random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)]
    multi_players_pos.append(pos)
```

or load `player_0.png` ... `player_9.png`:

```
multi_players = []
multi_players_pos = []

for i in range(10):
    temp = pygame.image.load("player_"+str(i)+".png").convert()
    temp.set_colorkey(white)
    multi_players.append(temp)
    pos = [random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)]
    multi_players_pos.append(pos)
```

draw it:

```
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        for i in range(len(multi_players)):
            screen.blit(multi_players[i], multi_players_pos)

        pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

The same way you can change players position.

But better way is to make `Player` class with all needed function.

(*it is not full code - so not tested*)

```
import random

class Player():

    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        image_rect = image.get_rect()

        self.rect = Rect(x, y, image_rect.width, image_rect.height)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)

    def update(self):
        # here change randomly positon

#--------------------------------------------

multi_players = []

#create 10 players 0...9
for i in range(10):
    x, y = random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)
    multi_players.append(Player("player_"+str(i)+".png", x, y))

while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # changes position

    for player in multi_players:
        player.update()

    # draws

    for player in multi_players:
        player.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working example - if you press any key (except ESC) images change position.

I use transparent PNG `ball1.png`, `ball2.png`, `ball3.png` so I don't use `.convert()` and `.set_colorkey()`.

Images you can find (and download) in answer to questions:

- [Space invaders project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966094/space-invaders-project/19966608#19966608)
- [Pygame- window and sprite class - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936347/pygame-window-and-sprite-class-python/19939076#19939076)

.

```
import random
import pygame

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Player():

    def __init__(self, image, x=0, y=0):

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)#.convert()
        #self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y

    #------------

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    #------------

    def update(self):
        # here change randomly positon
        self.rect.topleft = random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

        self.background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg").convert()
        self.multi_players = []

        # create 3 balls 1...3

        for i in range(1,4):
            player = Player("ball"+str(i)+".png")
            player.update() # set random position on start
            self.multi_players.append(player)

    #------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        RUNNING = True

        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False

                    # changes position when key is pressed

                    for player in self.multi_players:
                        player.update()

            # --- updates ---- 

            # place for updates

            # --- draws ---

            self.screen.fill(BLACK)

            self.screen.blit(self.background, self.background.get_rect())

            for player in self.multi_players:
                player.draw(self.screen)

            pygame.display.flip()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(20)

        # --- quit ---

        pygame.quit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

[image]

Comment: I was unable to get the code to run in my game. Whenever I use classes, my images never show up on screen.

Comment: This code expect images `player_1.png`, `player_2.png`, ...`player_9.png`. I had no full code so I couldn't test it. By the way now I see I made too big indentations.

Comment: I made full working example and I add my bitmaps and screenshot.

Comment: This worked well for me. I need to change a few things and tried looking at your example with the window and sprites class on the link above but got lost. I changed your Player class to an Enemy class successfully. I need to add the Player class as an image controlled by the arrow keys which I did in another program. Instead of any key being pressed I want the Enemy class to change randomly everytime I move the player. I need to add collision detection so the player goes back to the start if he hits an enemy. If he makes it past then he scores +7 and goes back to the start within a 2min timer.