# Image lags and stutters when moving

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason when I run the program, my baddie image (asteroid) lags and stutters when it moves however the target does not. I have tried putting `pygame.display.update()` under each movement code however it just flickers. Also, I switched the position of the movement code for the target and baddie which resulted in the target lagging and stuttering.

```
import pygame, sys, random
pygame.init()

def game():
    width = 800
    height = 600
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Asteroid Dodger")
    background = pygame.image.load("field_of_stars_full.jpg")


    player = pygame.image.load("Silver_Surfer.png")
    px = 350
    py = 450
    baddie = pygame.image.load("Asteroid.png")
    baddiepos = baddie.get_rect()
    target = pygame.image.load("Cosmic_Clump.png")
    targetpos = [0,0]

    gamespeed = 100
    speed = [gamespeed*random.randint(1,3),gamespeed*random.randint(1,3)]
    speed2 = [gamespeed*10,gamespeed*10]
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    movex = movey = 0

    targetvisible = True
    playervisible = True

    font = pygame.font.Font(None,36)

    score = 0
    scoretext = font.render("Score: " + str(score), 2, (255,255,255))
    lives = 3
    livestext = font.render("Lives: " + str(lives),2, (255,255,255))


    while True:


        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        screen.blit(player, (px,py))

        scoretext = font.render("Score: " + str(score), 2, (255,255,255))
        livestext = font.render("Lives: " + str(lives), 2, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(scoretext, (20,20))
        screen.blit(livestext, (670,20))

        if targetvisible == True:
            seconds = clock.tick()/1000.0
            targetpos[0] += seconds*speed[0]
            targetpos[1] += seconds*speed[1]
            screen.blit(target, targetpos)
        else:
            screen.blit(target, targetpos)



        if playervisible == True:
            seconds = clock.tick()/1000.0
            baddiepos[0] += seconds*speed2[0]
            baddiepos[1] += seconds*speed2[1]
            screen.blit(baddie, baddiepos)
        else:
            screen.blit(baddie, baddiepos)

        pygame.display.update()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        movex = 2
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        movex = -2
                        player = pygame.transform.flip(player, 1, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        movey = 2
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        movey = -2

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        movex = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        movex = 0
                        player = pygame.transform.flip(player, 1, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        movey = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        movey = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()

        px += movex
        py += movey

        if targetpos[0]+60 > width or targetpos[0]+15 < 0: 
            speed[0] = -speed[0]            
            targetpos[0] += seconds*speed[0]

        if targetpos[1]+70 > height or targetpos[1]+30 < 0:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]
            targetpos[1] += seconds*speed[1]

        if abs(targetpos[0]-px)<20 and abs(targetpos[1]-py)<20:
            targetvisible = False
            score += 10
            targetpos[0] = random.randint(0,720)
            targetpos[1] = random.randint(0,520)
            screen.blit(target, (targetpos))          
            targetvisible = True


        if baddiepos[0] > width or baddiepos[0] < 0:
            speed2[0] = -speed2[0]
            baddiepos[0] += seconds*speed2[0]

        if baddiepos[1] > height or baddiepos[1] < 0:
            speed2[1] = -speed2[1]
            baddiepos[1] += seconds*speed2[1]

        if abs(baddiepos[0]-px)<20 and (baddiepos[1]-py)<20:
            playervisble = False
            lives -= 1
            baddiepos[0] = random.randint(0,720)
            baddiepos[1] = random.randint(0,520)
            screen.blit(baddie, (baddiepos))
            playervisible = True

        if px > 800:
            px = 0
        elif px < 0:
            px = 800

        if py > 600:
            py = 0
        elif py < 0:
            py = 600
```

Comment: Why are you not using `pygame.time.delay()` ?

Answer (score 0):

`baddie` position depends on variable `second` which depends on `clock.tick()`.

From the [pygame.clock.tick()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#Clock.tick) documentation:

> It will compute how many
>   milliseconds have passed since the previous call (clock.tick()).

So it give you values 0 - 0.001 but mostly 0. So `baddie` mostly doesn't move.

Documentation:

> This method should be called once per frame.

Maybe you were going to use [pygame.time.get_ticks()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) but I don't know why you need it.

---

Your code could look like this:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

#~ PLAYER_IMAGE     = "ball2.png"
#~ TARGET_IMAGE     = "ball3.png"
#~ BADDIE_IMAGE     = "ball1.png"
#~ BACKGROUND_IMAGE = "background.jpg"

PLAYER_IMAGE     = "Silver_Surfer.png"
TARGET_IMAGE     = "Cosmic_Clump.png"
BADDIE_IMAGE     = "Asteroid.png"
BACKGROUND_IMAGE = "field_of_stars_full.jpg"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Player():

    def __init__(self, screen_rect):

        self.screen_rect = screen_rect

        self.image = pygame.image.load(PLAYER_IMAGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = 350
        self.rect.centery = 450

        self.move_x = self.move_y = 0

        self.visible = True

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)

    def flip(self):
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, 1, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.move_x
        self.rect.y += self.move_y

        if self.rect.centerx > self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.left
        elif self.rect.centerx < self.screen_rect.left:
            self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.right

        if self.rect.centery > self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.top
        elif self.rect.centery < self.screen_rect.top:
            self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def event_handler(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.move_x = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.move_x = -5
                self.flip()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.move_y = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.move_y = -5

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

            if event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_LEFT):
                self.move_x = 0

            elif event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_UP):
                self.move_y = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.flip()     

    def random_position(self):

        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0,720)
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(0,520)               
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Baddie():

    def __init__(self, screen_rect, speed):

        self.screen_rect = screen_rect

        self.image = pygame.image.load(BADDIE_IMAGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.speed_x = speed * random.randint(1,3)
        self.speed_y = speed * random.randint(1,3)

        self.visible = True

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)

    def update(self, player_visible):

        if player_visible:

            self.rect.x += self.speed_x * random.randint(1, 5)
            self.rect.y += self.speed_y * random.randint(1, 5)

            if self.rect.centerx > self.screen_rect.right:
                self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.left
            elif self.rect.centerx < self.screen_rect.left:
                self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.right

            if self.rect.centery > self.screen_rect.bottom:
                self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.top
            elif self.rect.centery < self.screen_rect.top:
                self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def random_position(self):

        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0,720)
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(0,520)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Target():

    def __init__(self, screen_rect, speed):

        self.screen_rect = screen_rect

        self.image = pygame.image.load(TARGET_IMAGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = 100
        self.rect.centery = 100

        self.speed_x = speed * 10
        self.speed_y = speed * 10

        self.visible = True

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)

    def update(self, screen):

        if self.visible:
            self.rect.x += self.speed_x
            self.rect.y += self.speed_y

            if self.rect.right > self.screen_rect.right or self.rect.left < 0: 
                self.speed_x = -self.speed_x            

            if self.rect.bottom > self.screen_rect.bottom or self.rect.top < 0:
                self.speed_y = -self.speed_y  

    def random_position(self):

        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0,720)
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(0,520)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        width = 800
        height = 600

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Asteroid Dodger")

        # --- variables ---

        self.score = 0
        self.lives = 3

        self.gamespeed = 1

        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None,36)

        self.scoretext = self.font.render("Score: " + str(self.score), 2, (255,255,255))
        self.livestext = self.font.render("Lives: " + str(self.lives), 2, (255,255,255))

        self.pausetext = self.font.render("PAUSE", 2, (255,255,255))
        # center pausetext on screen
        self.pausetext_rect = self.pausetext.get_rect(center=self.screen.get_rect().center)

        # --- sprites ---

        self.background = pygame.image.load(BACKGROUND_IMAGE)

        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.player = Player(screen_rect)

        self.baddie = Baddie(screen_rect, self.gamespeed)

        self.target = Target(screen_rect, self.gamespeed)

    #----------------------------------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        RUNNING = True
        PAUSED  = False

        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        PAUSED = not PAUSED

                self.player.event_handler(event)

            # --- updates ---

            if not PAUSED:
                self.player.update()
                self.baddie.update(self.player.visible)
                self.target.update(self.player.visible)

                # detect cilision
                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, self.baddie):
                    self.lives -= 1
                    self.player.random_position()

                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, self.target):
                    self.score += 10
                    self.target.random_position()

                self.scoretext = self.font.render("Score: " + str(self.score), 2, (255,255,255))
                self.livestext = self.font.render("Lives: " + str(self.lives), 2, (255,255,255))

            # --- draws ---

            self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))

            self.player.draw(self.screen)
            self.baddie.draw(self.screen)
            self.target.draw(self.screen)

            self.screen.blit(self.scoretext, (20,20))
            self.screen.blit(self.livestext, (670,20))


            if PAUSED:
                self.screen.blit(self.pausetext, self.pausetext_rect)

            pygame.display.update()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(25) # 25 Frames Per Second

        # --- the end ---

        pygame.quit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

ps. if someone needs images 'ball1.png', 'ball2.png', 'ball3.png' to run this example you can find it in answer to

- [Space invaders project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966094/space-invaders-project/19966608#19966608)
- [Pygame- window and sprite class - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936347/pygame-window-and-sprite-class-python/19939076#19939076)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
pygame.image.load("image").**convert**()
```

or
    pygame.image.load("image").**convert_alpha**() for png

Comment: I guess this does not look like you intended. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help I recommend to [edit] and not to try to mix bold and code formatting.