# Why doesnt my sprite move?

Tags: python, background, pygame, sprite, blit

I'm new to Pygame and I'm trying to move my sprite on my background image.
My sprite is not re appearing after it moves? Any ideas?
This is most of the program without some screens.
I have been trying to get this to work for many hours,

```
  #dependencies
import pygame as P
import random as R

def welcome(screen):
    #load background
    bg = P.image.load("space-wallpaper.jpg")
    screen.blit(bg,[0,0])

    #set fonts etc
    font = P.font.Font("Space_Age.ttf",60)
    width, height = screen.get_size()

    #play button
    message = "PLAY "
    text = font.render(message,1,[255 , 0, 0])
    rect = text.get_rect()
    x, y = text.get_size()
    rect = rect.move((width - x)/2, (height - y)/2)
    screen.blit(text,rect)

    #high_score button
    message = "HIGH SCORE "
    text = font.render(message,1,[255 , 0, 0])
    rect = text.get_rect()
    x, y = text.get_size()
    rect = rect.move((width - x)/2, (height - y)/2 +100)
    screen.blit(text,rect)

def play_button(screen):
    """launch welcome screen.

    """
    #welcome screen play button
    font = P.font.Font("Space_Age.ttf",60)
    message = "PLAY "
    play_x,play_y = font.size(message)
    play_text = font.render(message,1,[255 , 0, 0])
    width, height = 800,600
    screen.blit(play_text,[(width - play_x)/2, (height - play_y)/2])
    play_rect = play_text.get_rect().move((width - play_x)/2, (height - play_y)/2)
    P.display.flip()
    return(play_rect)

def welcome_background(screen):
    # Welcome screen background
    bg = P.image.load("space-wallpaper.jpg")
    screen.blit(bg,[0,0])
    P.display.update()


def high_score_screen(screen):


 """opens the highscore screen"""
    high_score_bg = P.image.load("bg_game.jpg")
    screen.blit(high_score_bg,[0,0])
    P.display.update()

def splash_screen(screen):
    """loads the first screen in the game with a 3 sec wait"""
    splash_image = P.image.load('splash.jpg')
    screen.blit(splash_image,[0,0])
    P.display.update()
    P.time.wait(2001)

def play_game(screen):
    """loads the play game screen"""
    game_bg = P.image.load("bg_game.jpg")
    screen.blit(game_bg,[0,0])
    P.display.update()

def move_right(screen,x_cord,flagship):

    dist = 20
    play_game(screen)
    x_cord = x_cord + dist
    print(x_cord)
    screen.blit(flagship,[x_cord])
    P.display.update()

def key_detection(screen,flagship,x_cord):


     key = P.key.get_pressed()
     if key[P.K_RIGHT]:
        move_right(screen,x_cord,flagship)
        #move_right()



     elif key[P.K_LEFT]:
        print("left")






class Sprite():
    def __init__(self,screen):
        """ The constructor of the class """
        self.flagship = P.image.load("sprite2.png")

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def display(self,screen):
        #screen.blit(self.sprite,[self.x,self.y]) changed by geoff
        screen.blit(self.flagship,[self.x,self.y])
        P.display.update()





_init_

# dependencies
from mods import *
import pygame as P

#initialise pygame
P.init()


def main():
    # parameters to control pygame basics
    screen_size = width, height = 800,600 #sixe of playing screen
    P.display.set_caption('Space Smasher!')
    screen = P.display.set_mode(screen_size)
    clock = P.time.Clock() # timer used to control rate of looping
    loop_rate = 20 #number of times per second does loop
    play = True #control the playing of the actual game
    splash_screen(screen)
    welcome(screen)
    P.display.flip()
    rect_play = play_button(screen)
    flagship = Sprite(screen)
    while play:
        key_detection(screen,flagship.image,flagship.x)
#        for event in P.event.poll(): changed by geoff
        event = P.event.poll() #did the player do something?
        if event.type == P.QUIT:
            play = False


        if event.type == P.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            player_position = P.mouse.get_pos()
            if rect_play.collidepoint(player_position):
                play_game(screen)
                flagship.display(screen)



    P.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is it all you have ? Where is `mainloop` ? You have to blit sprite in mainloop in every loop.

Comment: Hello Thankyou for taking time to help me it is highly appreciated. I will update it now with the whole program.

Comment: You can give link to external place with code.

Comment: Sure please give me one sec,

Comment: You have to display flagship in all loops and move it to expected position.

Comment: I have uploaded the whole game to http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/549072/Just-Game---Copy-zip.html

Comment: or if you would like I am happy to email it to you?

Comment: For now see some examples in my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936347/pygame-window-and-sprite-class-python/19939076#19939076

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963271/pygame-display-multiple-images-randomly/19963818#19963818

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling either of your functions or your classes anywhere. You need a while loop that is similarly structured to this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    #Do your movements
```

With the following imports at the top:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
```

Here is an example of moving an object with the keys:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
WIDTH=1439
HEIGHT=791
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello Pygame World!')
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 10)
circx, circy = 200, 150
CIRWIDTH=20
while True: # main game loop
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
        circy-=5
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        circy+=5
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        circx+=5
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        circx-=5
    try:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT or event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
    except AttributeError:
            pass
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, (158, 219, 222), (circx, circy), CIRWIDTH)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Main loop should be similar to:

```
while True:

     # events - check keyboad and mouse and change player direction or speed

     # move - move sprite with speed and direction

     # check collison

     # draw background, all objects and all sprites

     # clock - to keep constant speed - FPS (Frames Per Seconds)
```

So you have to move sprites in every loop and draw them.

Comment: So im not drawing the new sprite to the background?

Comment: You have so many `display.update()` so it hard to recognize which ones are executed and which one overwrite flagship.

Comment: `move_right` should only change `cord_x`. `blit(flagship,...)` and `display.update()`  should be use only once in main loop.