# pygame: is it possible to fill the screen with image instead of color?

Tags: python, pygame

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import sys
import pygame


class MyGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
        pygame.init()

        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        self.bg_img = pygame.image.load('pokebg.jpeg')

        self.FPS = 30
        self.REFRESH = pygame.USEREVENT+1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.REFRESH, 1000//self.FPS)


    def run(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            event = pygame.event.wait()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == self.REFRESH:
                self.draw()

            else:
                pass         

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_img)

        pygame.display.flip()


MyGame().run()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

i want to have an image instead of color as a background, but it the error says "invalid color argument" is there a way to fix this or the only way to fill the screen is with color? or use a different filling method?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line `self.screen.fill(self.bg_img)` with `self.screen.blit(self.bg_img, self.bg_img.get_rect())`.  This will work only if the image is the exact same size as the screen.  If it isn't you should use `pygame.transform.scale`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `fill()` with image you can only `blit()` image on screen. If you use loop you can fill all screen.

You can see code and screenshot with screen filled using "ball" image in my answer to question [Pygame- window and sprite class - python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19939076/1832058)